# Getting a cell number from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm making an iPhone app with a Table View, and I'm trying to place a different icon / image next to each cell on a table.

I know that you set the image in `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` with code that looks like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I target a specific cell, so that it has a unique image?  Like:

```
if (cell.number == 0) {
    //Use a specific image
}
else if (cell.number == 1) {
    //Use a different image
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `indexPath` variable contains information about the cell's position. Modifying your example:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
  // Use a specific image.
}
```

See the [NSIndexPath Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) for more information. It's also important to note that cell numbers reset in each section.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll read up on Apple's documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `row` (and possibly also `section`) properties in the NSIndexPath passed to your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to identify which cell is being queried.

Answer (score 0):

this function is passed an index path, which has a section and a row. indexPath.row will pass back an integer you can check.

Answer (score 0):

When cellForRowAtIndexPath is executed you have access to the indexPath variable, so if you want to customize the cell style depending on the cell index you can do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // code for cell 0
    }
    else {
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            // code for cell 1
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example, I don't think that customizing your cells by using if conditions is the best idea, but it shows you how to do what you need.

Remember that indexPath contains the section of the table too. If you are using a Grouped table view, you need to manager the section too. For example:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    // section 0
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // code for section 0 - cell 0
    }
    else {
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            // code for section 0 - cell 1
        }
    }        
}
else {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        // section 1
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // code for section 1 - cell 0
        }
        else {
            if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                // code for section 1 - cell 1
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly nicer looking approach I would put all the images you want to use into an array:

```
_iconArray = @[@"picture1.png", @"picture2.png", @"picture3.png"];
```

This means that when you come to the cellForRowAtIndex function you can say only:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_iconArray[indexPath.row]];
```

This is also easier if you have more than one section, this time you can make an array of arrays, each containing the required pictures for the different sections.

```
_sectionsArray = @[_iconArray1, _iconArray2, _iconArray3];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_sectionsArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

This immediately makes it very easy to modify the pictures (as you are only dealing with the arrays. And much easier if you have more rows and sections (imagine doing it manually for 100 rows)